# Wiring 3 way switch (es) in a box

Tags: electrical, switch

I have some lights that are not turning on and I'm assuming it's controlled by the box that I'm looking in.

In the box there is 4 cables coming in. I took all the wires out, other than neutrals(white) I have those connected together (4 neutrals) with a wire nut.

Here is the information on individual cables:

One cable always has power on. Has black, white and ground wire.

There is another cable with black, white and neutral and it has no power(not connected to anything other than neutral to other neutrals like mentioned above).

There are two cables with red, black, and white wires. Here is the photo:

[image: wires sticking out of the box in the wall]

There is another 3 way switch (with one red, one black and one neutral) that has no power at all. I assume is connected to this box.

How should I wire these? Do I need two 3 way switches? One I can connect it all to one?

At this point it doesn't matter to me one or two switches.

Comment: Did it *ever* work?  Usually the way you know which wires do what is "how it was connected when you found it".  Removing all the devices and splaying the wires out makes the assumption that they're color-coded or something... they're not. Really, really not.

Comment: We can _assume_ (but you know what happens when you do that), that the one with power when everything is disconnected is the hot from the box, that the /3 cables (with a black & red) go to the switched loads (the lights that turn on), and that the other /2 cable carries unswitched power to some other load (receptacle or another light switch somewhere else), but that's all we can tell for sure (and even that's just a SWAG) from this picture. Post the pic from _before_ you pulled all the wires apart.

Comment: I don't have the photo from before. It wasn't working then as well